# Errors reported by "powercfg -energy"

Tags: power-management

Running ["powercfg -energy"](http://howtoinwindows.com/windows-7/troubleshooting-errors/powercfg-sleep-mode-power-problems/) under Windows 7 command line, I received a report with following three errors:

```
System Availability Requests:Away Mode Request
The program has made a request to enable Away Mode.
Requesting Process  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmpnetwk.exe

CPU Utilization:Processor utilization is high
The average processor utilization during the trace was high. The system will consume less power when the average processor utilization is very low. Review processor utilization for individual processes to determine which applications and services contribute the most to total processor utilization.
Average Utilization (%)     49.25

Platform Power Management Capabilities:PCI Express Active-State Power Management (ASPM) Disabled
PCI Express Active-State Power Management (ASPM) has been disabled due to a known incompatibility with the hardware in this computer.
```

I was wondering

1. for the first error, what does
   "enable away mode" mean?
2. for the second, what utilization
   percentage of CPU is reasonable?
3. for the third, what is "PCI Express
   Active-State Power Management
   (ASPM)"?
4. How I can correct the three errors?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: In a bit of a hurry to answer properly, sorry; that said, I wouldn't worry about any of these.